# Which one of the following is correct?

Tags: probability

> In an examination $30 \%$ of the students failed in Mathematics, $15 \%$ of the students failed in English and
>   $10 \%$ of the students failed in both Mathematics and English. A student is chosen at random. If he failed in
>   English then the probability that he passed in Mathematics is
>
> $(a)$ $\frac {1} {2}.$
>
> $(b)$ $\frac {1} {10}.$
>
> $(c)$ $\frac {1} {3}.$
>
> $(d)$ $\frac {7} {10}.$

**My attempt** $:$

Suppose if we take $100$ students as the total number of students in the class. Then out of these $100$ the number of students qualify in Mathematics is $70$ and the number of students qualify in English is $85$. Since $10$ were failed in both the subjects. So the total number of students who qualify in both the subjects is $70+85-90=65.$ So the number of students who have qualified in Mathematics but not in English is $70-65=5.$ Now the total number of students who have not qualified in English is given as $15$ and hence the required probability is $\frac {5} {15}$ which simplifies to $\frac {1} {3}.$ So according to me $(c)$ is the correct option.

Is the above reasoning correct at all? Please verify it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, correct! No need to figure out all those who passed both subjects though. You just needed to point out that out of the 15 that failed English, 10 also failed Math, so 5 out of the 15 that failed English passed Math which is $\frac{1}{3}$